# I have a valid H1-B visa. I am going to India from the US via Heathrow. Do I need a UK transit visa?

Tags: visas, uk, transit

I already went to this site and put in my info:

https://www.gov.uk/check-uk-visa/y/india/transit/somewhere_else/no

It said:
You’ll need a visa to pass through the UK in transit (unless you’re exempt)
You should apply for a Direct Airside Transit visa if you arrive in the UK on a flight and leave again without passing through immigration control.

Exemptions
You don’t need a visa if you have one of the following:

a visa for Canada, New Zealand, Australia or the USA (this can be used for travel to any country)

This is the what the site said on Monday September 4th 2017.

However I did read in a StackExchange thread from 2013 I believe where they said I had to have entered US 6 months prior or some rule like that, I do not see that rule anymore.

SO just wanted to verify before I booked my ticket.
Last time when I flew British Airways, they were kind enough to send me on another airline as I did not have a H1-B stamp.

This time I have a stamped H1-B so, I am assuming if the site has nothing I am not aware of. I can transit via London with just my Valid, unexpired H1-B stamped on my passport.

Thanks.
Whitchurch